# Why is the output for the id variable 1?

Tags: fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int id;
    printf("here comes the date.\n");
    if (id = fork() == 0) {
        printf(“%d”, id);
        printf ("PID is %d and ID  is %d\n", getpid (),id);
        execl ("/bin/date", "date", 0);
    }
    printf ("that was the date.\n");
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
here comes the date.
that was the date.
PID is 1414 and ID  is 1
Tue Feb 10 14:03:02 PST 2015
```

Comment: That's because the [operators precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm): `=` has lesser precedence than `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are setting it equal to the result of `fork() == 0` which is a logical test.

Fork will succeed (return zero) inside of the forked thread.  The outer thread will have the PID.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I thought it was supposed to take the zero because that is what fork() returns in the child. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Any time.  :)  Please accept the answer when you confirm it.